# preg_match match up to an optional character then ignore remaining text

Tags: preg-match, design-patterns, option-type

I have the following string format:

```
[[TEXT|TEXT]] <-- the "|TEXT" is optional
```

And so far what works fine is:

```
/([^\[]+)(?=\]\])/
```

Which will return:

```
TEXT
or
TEXT|TEXT
```

I want to match up to "|TEXT" if it has been included and only ever match the left side of "|" or "]]" depending on which is first.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** - if you only want to match what's in the `[[]]` and not including the `|TEXT` if it's there, try this:

```
([^|\[]+?)(?=(?:\]\]|\|))
```

Which is more-or-less your starting regex but it stops at a `|` or a `]]`.

Or if your regex flavour supports look-behinds you could do:

```
((?<=\[\[)([^\|]+?)(?=(?:\]\]|\|))
```

This just enforces that you match from `[[` onwards. Not really necessary but a bit more unknown-content-proof.

Comment: Thanks although I've hopefully made the question bit clearer now. I want to match up to "|TEXT" if it has been included and only match and return the left side of "|" not replace it. The optional `\|` doesnt seem to match when used such as `\|?.*\]\]`.